# Pattern for displaying text on a web page that originated from a <textarea>

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

### Problem

What is a simple and effective pattern for displaying text on a web page that originated from a `<textarea>` element while preserving for orginal formatting?

### Goal

The goal is to allow the client to type whatever the feel like into a `<textarea>` and for them to be able to view it later with all the characters and line breaks that they used preserved.

Anything using Javascript, Jquery, or Backbone would be great.

### More info

The three (flawed) methods that I've tried to far:

- Displaying the text using `jQuery('element').html()`

  - The problem with this method is that html-relevant characters that the client may have chosen to type into the textarea are interpreted as html, such as `>` and `<`
- Displaying the text using `jQuery('element').text()`

  - The problem with this method is that all of the line breaks that the client chose to use are discarded.
- Displaying the text in a read-only `<textarea>` element.

  - The problem with this method is that its difficult to get the `<textarea>` to expand to the exact size of the text. It also leaves a little to be desired in terms for attractive formatting.

Comment: so you want to convert line breaks into `<br>` and special characters to UTF-8, is that correct?

Comment: That would be one approach. I'm not really sure that the best pattern for handling this situation would be though.

Answer (score 1):

```
str.replace(/\x26/g,'\x26amp;')     // first do all & to &amp;
   .replace(/\x3c/g,'\x26lt;')      // next do < to &lt;
   .replace(/\r\n|\n/g,'\x3cbr>');  // finally replace new lines with <br>
// Note: I chose hex char code to exclude the 'risky' characters from the code,
//  that way they are also safe for inline-scripts (in older browsers).
// Also, I used local setting char-notation, not unicode, 
//  as they are the same for this purpose (and it saves some chars).
```

- Note: the order of replacements is important.
- Also note: this sequence did *NOT end* with an attempt to preserve whitespace (aka, avoid the white-space collapsing feature of HTML) by finding a '[HTML equivalent to &nbsp; …that DOES break;](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24468873/588079)' (and replace spaces with that) *because* **it is much simpler** to use a `pre` tag to hold the contents (seems better for older browsers, notably IE<9) *or* disable the white-space collapsing feature in CSS: `div.preview {white-space: [pre|pre-wrap];}`

Simple example ([live jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/njcj6dL4/)):

```
<textarea style="width:98%" onkeyup="
this.nextSibling.innerHTML=this.value.replace(/\x26/g,'\x26amp;')
                                     .replace(/\x3c/g,'\x26lt;')
                                     .replace(/\r\n|\n/g,'\x3cbr>');
"></textarea><pre></pre>
```

Note, you might also want to hook `onchange` etc.. also, you might want to have a separate function and cache the output (and input) element(s).

You could make this a lot more difficult, for example only replace the `&` when absolutely needed, the same goes for `<`.
Also you could transform all unwanted (non-'ASCII') characters to their unicode HTML-entity equivalent, but all this seems a little overkill for a simple preview as you probably want don't want to submit the user's data in this (overly effective) html-markup. A simple example for that would have been:

```
.replace(/[^\u0020-\u007e]/g, function(m){return '\x26#'+m.charCodeAt(0)+';';})
```

Hope this gets you started.

**EDIT 1:** Also have a look at [demo jsFiddle v2](http://jsfiddle.net/njcj6dL4/2/) and [demo jsFiddle v3](http://jsfiddle.net/njcj6dL4/3/) for some more advanced examples like:

```
(  // START HTML encoder hookup 
 function(enc, e1, e2, e3){
   (e1.onkeyup = function(){
      e3.innerHTML = e2.value = enc(e1.value);
   })();
 }( // IIFE Passing encoder and elements
   (function(){  //HTML enc
      var  amp=/\x26/g  ,  lte=/\x3c/g  ,  eol=/\r\n|\n/g
      , noASCI=/[^\u0020-\u007e]/g
      , toUCPd=function(m){ return '\x26#'+ m.charCodeAt(0) +';'; }
      ;
      return function(s){return( 
        s.replace(amp, '\x26amp;')
         .replace(lte, '\x26lt;')
         .replace(eol, '\x3cbr>')
         .replace(noASCI, toUCPd)      //optional
      );};
    }
   )() //IIFE returns HTML enc
 , document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]
 , document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[1]
 , document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0]
 )
); // END HTML encoder hookup

/* Corresponding demo html:
Input:<br>
<textarea>&#9;&lt;this is a tab char  &  these &#9786;&#235; non-'ASCII'
continue to to type here</textarea><br>
Generated HTML code:<br>
<textarea>code output</textarea><br>
HTML output in pre:<br>
<pre>html output</pre>
*/
```

**EDIT 2:** almost forgot, you could look at the (quirky, forgotten but still valid) [`xmp`-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784925/588079). That would work until the user types `</xmp`. Note for older IE: replace the whole xmp-element instead of setting/overwriting it's `innerHTML` (because that doesn't work at least in IE6). However, as noted, there are a lot of quirks to this `xmp`-tag regarding box-layout, overflow etc over the different browsers!